# What to look / check for when can't connect to Vagrant VM made using the Drupal Vagrant project?

Tags: virtual-machine

Using my Mac as the host machine, I followed all the instructions on the Drupal Vagrant project page at http://drupal.org/project/vagrant to get a Vagrant automated Virtual Box Ubuntu lucid32 Virtual Machine up and running with a Drupal 7 stack.

However when I try to use my browser to connect to the server, using the URL addresses stated in the instructions on the project page, it doesn't work.

(The same steps work when using Windows 7 as the host machine.)

The error message, for example, in Chrome is:
"Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to dev-site.vbox.local"

The Vagrant VM seems to be running OK and I can connect to it using vagrant ssh.

I also flushed the DNS cache using
dscacheutil -flushcache

and I tried all of the following:
http://drupal.vbox.local/
http://drupal.vbox.local/index.php
http://drupal.vbox.local/install.php
http://drupal.vbox.local/phpmyadmin

http://dev-site.vbox.local/
http://dev-site.vbox.local/index.php
http://dev-site.vbox.local/install.php
http://dev-site.vbox.local/phpmyadmin/

Mac OS 10.7.5. 4GB RAM. MacBookPro 2010.

Comment: use this command to flush DNS `killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, tried it, no change - still problem, got message: "No matching processes belonging to you were found"

Comment: Note to self: check apache logs?

Comment: I don't think apache logs has anything to do with your problem. did you use sudo with it?!

Comment: tried with sudo. same outcome. sorry. but thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Inside your Vagrant box (after doing `vagrant ssh` i.e.), can you check the IP? Do a `ifconfig`. Ensure it's the same as the static IP you'd have used in your hosts' `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: I will check that and get back to you @AmarnathRavikumar

Comment: Did [this](http://serverfault.com/a/597621/103459) help?